# How to assign array of values to Excel cells without losing table formatting in VSTO

Tags: excel, formatting, vsto

This may be an easy one, but it escapes me at the moment. I have reworded the question based on some new findings.

I use 2D arrays of values extensively in Excel add-ins for the raw speed increase that gives.

I use extension methods to extract a cell array and modify it, then put the values back.

### e.g.:

```
// Get all cells in the worksheet - this is a formatted table including headings
Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

// Get all values as a 2D array
object[,] cells = range.GetCellArray();

... // do things to the array 

// Assign the entire array back to worksheet, but table formatting is erased
Range.Value = cells;
```

the table formatting only gets removed by the array assignment. This goes as far as the named table `ListObject` entry being removed.

### Is there a way to keep the table formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you replace the cells of the heading row, of a formatted table, you lose the table completely.

The solution is to replace only the rows under the heading.

```
// Get all cells in the worksheet - this is a formatted table including headings
Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

// Get all values as a 2D array
object[,] cells = range.GetCellArray();

... // do things to the array 

// Assign the entire array MINUS THE HEADING ROW, back to worksheet
cells = cells.SubArray(2, 1, cells.RowCount() - 1, cells.ColumnCount());
EXCEL.Range targetRange = worksheet.GetRange(1, 2, cells.ColumnCount(), cells.RowCount());
targetRange.Value = cells;
```

The `SubArray`, `GetRange`, `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` methods are all extension methods I created previously, but you get the idea what they do from their names and the example.

Comment: Ah, that was not so mysterious after all.  I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way, but my first thought was to output the array to a temporary sheet, then copy the output and Paste Special -> Values only onto your desired range. Finally, delete the temporary sheet.

Comment: That is definitely one of the last things I would want. The overhead of doing that per sheet would kill this app (currently updates whole sheets quite frequently). Thanks anyway.

Comment: I figured, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: BTW, I tested this in VBA and didn't observe any loss of formatting (number format, font, fill).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my last comment.  I meant that I tried the procedure that YOU described in your post, in VBA, and I didn't observe any loss of formatting.  So, I'm not sure if that means there's something fundamentally different between how VBA reads ranges into arrays (and vice versa) and how VSTO does it, or if maybe you've somehow lost the formatting in virtue of something else in your code.

Comment: Question re-worded as it is actually a table formatting issue (not basic cell formatting). There may now also be a specific solution... will try some theories tonight.